# Deleting elements under a specific value in a list

Tags: c

So far I've written this piece of code. Here's my structure, but really all I use is the avg field in this function.

```
 struct grade
 {
   char *crs;
   int grd;
 };
 struct student
 {
    char *name;
    int yr;
    struct grade grades[3];
    float avg;
    struct student *nxt;

}*root;
```

And now this is the respective function which causes a segmentation fault when called.

```
void delete_failed()
{
    struct student *i=root;
    for (;i->nxt!=NULL;i=i->nxt);
    if (i->nxt->avg<5.00)
    {
      struct student *j=i->nxt;
      i->nxt=i->nxt->nxt;
      free(j);
      delete_failed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I really don't see the point in making this recursive, that sounds very confusing and bad for performance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your function. For a start the for loop checks for `i->nxt` not being NULL. What if the list is empty? That would make `i` be NULL and lead to a crash.

Secondly, that for loop skips over most of the list until the last element (namely when `i->nxt` is NULL), which doesn't seem particularly useful. Especially as you start doing things with `i->nxt` which is NULL.

So in either case, your function will crash.

Here is a revised version...

```
void delete_failed()
{
    struct student *i,*last=NULL,*next_i;
    for (i=root;i!=NULL;i=next_i)
    {
        next_i=i->nxt;
        if (i->avg<5.00)
        {
           if(last)
           {
               last->nxt=i->nxt;
           }
           else
           {
               root = i->nxt;
           }
           if(i->name) free(i->name);
           free(i);
           }
       }
       else
       {
           last=i;
       }
    }
}
```

- It tracks the last element that was kept. This way it knows if you're
  removing elements from the beginning of the list and can update
  `root` accordingly or it can point `last->nxt` to `i->nxt`.
- It keeps a copy of `i->nxt` in `next_i` before doing anything else, so that it can use it to update `i` for the next iteration of the loop.
- It also frees `i->name` which was not included originally and by the looks of it is needed as a it's a `char *`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but..

```
for (;i->nxt !=NULL;i=i->nxt);
```

This increments `i` until `i == NULL`.

Then, in the code following that loop you try to dereference `i` and use it's values, that's undefined behaviour and thus you get a segfault.

Perhaps you meant :

```
for (;i->nxt!=NULL;i=i->nxt)
{
  if (i->nxt->avg<5.00)
  {
    struct student *j=i->nxt;
    i->nxt=i->nxt->nxt;
    free(j);
    delete_failed();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, same reasoning.

Comment: Well I save the reference to the student with the average<5 in j, then I make i->nxt skip over j, then I delete j and repeat the process, until eventually there will be no students with averages <5 and the program will stop.

Comment: Well at least that's what I wanna do